# The reason of starting a line with colon ":" in zsh_history file

Tags: format, zsh

I'm using the zsh history plugin, which adds the timestamp of the command I entered. The raw file of the .zsh_history text file looks like below:

```
: 1582469132:0;jupyterlab
: 1582469132:0;jupyter notebook
: 1582469132:0;jupyterlab
: 1582469132:0;jupyter lab
: 1582469132:0;jupyter notebook
: 1582469132:0;ls
```

I just don't understand the reason for using this format that why every line item starts with a colon `:`?

I'm pretty sure this plugin is not the only one using this format. I've seen SWIFT messages using this format and some other file which I couldn't remember the name.

Comment: Understanding that the format works to add timestamps to a history file, and the history file can be executed as a script is one matter. Understanding the _reason_ is really a question for the plugin authors.

Comment: @JackeyOL : What other character would **you** expect instead of the colon? If it were, say, a `#`, executing the line would be considered as a comment, and nothing would be run. By having a colon, the part after the `;` is executed correctly and the timestamp itself does not have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I believe the leading colon allows you to execute the history file as a script.

`:` is a do-nothing command: it ignores its arguments then completes with an exit status of 0. In this case, the argument is the string `<timestamp>:0`; the semicolon is a command terminator.

You can try it out at the prompt:

```
% : 1235:0;echo hello
hello
```

Thus, executing this file as a script would have the same affect as executing

```
jupyterlab
jupyter notebook
jupyterlab
jupyter lab
jupyter notebook
ls
```

It's unlikely you would *want* to execute an arbitrary history file as a script, but a file containing a specially crafted history could be useful.